# Visual Studio 2019 v16.5.0 , .NET Framework 4.8.03752 Missing integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio, terminal, visual-studio-2019

I hope you all doing great.
[Microsoft announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/) that  Visual Studio version 16.3 and above has an integrated terminal, and we can activate it with going to "Tools > Options > Preview Features, enable the **Experimental VS Terminal** option"
, but my visual studio doesn't have that **option**.
anyone knows why, please help?[my vs2019 option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlg63.png)

YOU CAN SEE MICROSOFT ANNOUNCEMENT AND THE PIC OF THEIR TOOLS MENU: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrated terminal is still in preview. You need to run a [Visual Studio *Preview*](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) version 16.3 or later to get access to it. An [MSFT sanctioned post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/954442/view.html) suggests that the integrated terminal will make the release branch in the upcoming version 16.6.

> *Unfortunately we still have to finish some work before shipping the terminal on the release channel.*
>
> *While I can’t yet guarantee anything, our goal it to ship it with the 16.6 release and the team is currently working towards that end.*